# facebook api -> response code 206 -> an error occured

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

My error is -> an error occurred (not very helpful) when trying to do a basic Facebook app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta property="og:title" content="This Page Title">
<meta property="og:description" content="product">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://tpccommedia.com/fb_progs/redir.php?p=share">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mySiteName">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="229474487215744">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://telecom.com/images/nyclogo.png">
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1392552050964797&amp;display=popup&amp;caption=http://tpccommedia.com/fb_progs/redir.php?p=share">Share This App!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The output from the Facebook debugger only indicates and response code of 206, which I understand is to be expected?

```
Scrape Information
Response Code   206
Fetched URL http://tpccommedia.com/fb_progs/redir.php?p=share
Canonical URL   http://tpccommedia.com/fb_progs/redir.php?p=share
Object Properties
fb:app_id   229474487215744
og:url  http://tpccommedia.com/fb_progs/redir.php?p=share
og:type website
og:title    This Page Title
og:image    
og:description  product
og:site_name    mySiteName
og:updated_time 1383429465
Raw Open Graph Document Information
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="This Page Title" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="product" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://tpccommedia.com/fb_progs/redir.php?p=share" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="mySiteName" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="229474487215744" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://nyctelecomm.com/images/nyclogo.png" />
URLs
Graph API   https://graph.facebook.com/176103072585712
Scraped URL     See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL
```

I am not in sandbox mode as indicated in other post.
What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is with your link to "Share this App".

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1392552050964797&display=popup&caption=http://tpccommedia.com/fb_progs/redir.php?p=share

Make sure the app_id is correct (not a page Id) and that you have specified a redirect_uri as per the documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#redirect